# SoapCore .Net6.0 error Incorrect Content-Type: text/xml; charset=UTF-8

Tags: wcf, post, .net-6.0, content-type

i m having a problem with SoapCore.
The library i m using is https://github.com/DigDes/SoapCore, i have to migrate code from WCF service, i can make WCF endpoint but the JS client of the service get the error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Incorrect Content-Type: text/xml; charset=UTF-8
```

This is the program.cs:

```
    builder.Services.AddControllers().AddXmlSerializerFormatters().AddXmlDataContractSerializerFormatters();
    builder.Services.AddSoapCore();
    // Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
    builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
    builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
    builder.Services.AddSingleton<IWebAvisos, RemoteControlService>();
    
    var app = builder.Build();
    
    // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseSwagger();
        app.UseSwaggerUI();
    }
    app.UseRouting();
    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => {
        var encodes = new SoapEncoderOptions();
       
      
        endpoints.UseSoapEndpoint<IWebAvisos>("/ServicioAvisos/WebAvisos", encodes, SoapSerializer.XmlSerializer) ;
    });
app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.Run();
```

Interface:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IWebAvisos 
{
    [OperationContract]
    List<string> GetRemoteControl(int Id);
}
```

Class:

```
 public class RemoteControlService : IWebAvisos
    {
        
        public RemoteControlService()
        {
            
        }
      
        public List<string> GetRemoteControl([FromBody] int ObjId)
        {
            return new List<string>()
            {
                "1",
                "2"
            };
        }
    }
```

as you can see is a dummy example and has to work with  POST Xmlhttprequest from javascript since we have several clients and we need to be compatible with them:
This is the way i have to make the request and the server answer:

```
URL --> /ServicioAvisos/WebAvisos/GetRemoteControl
BODY --> <GetRemoteControl xmlns="http://tempuri.org/"><Id>0</Id></GetRemoteControl>
Headers --> 
Content-Type:text/xml; charset=UTF-8
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
```

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can check your bindings. Different bindings have different features for security encryption. And Then test other bindings to see if this type of error occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `OverwriteResponseContentType` to true as follows:

```
 var encodes = new SoapEncoderOptions() 
               { 
                   WriteEncoding = Encoding.UTF8, 
                   OverwriteResponseContentType = true 
               };
```

This resolved the issue for me in a .Net 6 app using SoapCore 1.1.0.36